# Swift: Is there any way to return a *type* (not an *instance*) as an opaque type?

Tags: swift, protocols, associated-types, opaque-types

Suppose we have a module with some private types that are not meant to be (directly) made use of by a client of the module. We can define a public protocol and implement that protocol with a private type:

```swift
public protocol PublicProtocol {
  func print()
}

private struct PrivateStruct : PublicProtocol {
  func print() {
    Swift.print("this is a private instance")
  }
}
```

Our module could then define some public method (or variable) to request the type conforming to this protocol:

```swift
public var PublicInstance: some PublicProtocol {
  return PrivateStruct()
}

PublicInstance.print()
//  This is a private instance.
```

Here, we use Swift Opaque Types to “hide” the actual return type from the client of this module; all the client sees is the `PublicProtocol` interface. This is good, as long as we are interested in just an *instance* of the `PrivateStruct`. If what we are interested in is the *type* of the `PrivateStruct`, things don't look that easy:

```swift
public protocol PublicProtocol {
  static func print()
}

private struct PrivateStruct : PublicProtocol {
  static func print() {
    Swift.print("This is a private type.")
  }
}

public var PublicInstance: some PublicProtocol.Type {
  return PrivateStruct.self
}
//  error: an 'opaque' type must specify only 'Any', 'AnyObject', protocols, and/or a base class
```

We can't use an opaque return type here (AFAIK). Could we return the `PublicProtocol` type itself?

```swift
public var PublicType: PublicProtocol.Type {
  return PrivateStruct.self
}

PublicType.print()
//  This is a private type.
```

That works, unless our `PublicProtocol` defines an `associatedtype`:

```swift
public protocol PublicProtocol {
  associatedtype ChildType
  
  static func print()
}

private struct PrivateStruct : PublicProtocol {
  typealias ChildType = Void
  
  static func print() {
    Swift.print("This is a private type.")
  }
}

//  error: protocol 'PublicProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

In theory, we might (someday) have the ability to fix this with a public `typealias`:

```swift
public typealias PublicType : some PublicProtocol = PrivateStruct

error: 'some' types are only implemented for the declared type of properties and subscripts and the return type of functions
```

We don't have functionality like this today (AFAIK).

We could just declare `PrivateStruct` as a `public` type:

```swift
public protocol PublicProtocol {
  associatedtype ChildType
  
  static func print()
}

public struct PrivateStruct : PublicProtocol {
  public typealias ChildType = Void
  
  public static func print() {
    Swift.print("This is a private type.")
  }
}

public typealias PublicType = PrivateStruct

PublicType.print()
//  This is a private type.
```

This “works”, except our `private` type is now `public` to the client of this module.

Is there any way to return a *type* (not an *instance*) as an opaque type? Is there any other support for doing something like this somewhere else in Swift?

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting idea. I think it’s fundamentally limited, because the type would leak if you just call `type(of:)` on the result

Answer (score 0):

```
public protocol PublicProtocol {
  associatedtype PrivateConstraint
  
  static func print()
}

private struct PrivateStruct : PublicProtocol {
  typealias PrivateConstraint = Void
  
  static func print() {
    Swift.print("This is a private type.")
  }
}

public var PublicType: any PublicProtocol.Type {
  return PrivateStruct.self
}

PublicType.print()
//  This is a private type.
```

This code works using the `any` keyword introduced in Swift 5.6.